# Retreiving the encoding from Azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm implementing the Azure function that listens the CSV files uploading into the blob storage (using blob trigger). There are a different encoding that can be used for this CSV file like UTF8, UTF8-BOM, etc.
So, my listener should be able to retrieve an actual encoding from the blob.

How can I achieve this?
I can see an appropriate property in Azure UI for the blob, however this property is always empty...

I'm expecting that Azure add information about encoding during blob uploading process.

Comment: could you share your code(or) could tell c#,python (or) etc

Comment: CloudBlobContainer container = blobContainerFactory.getClient(accountsToProcessContainer);
        CloudBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(accountsFileName);

        try (
                BlobInputStream blobIS = blob.openInputStream();
                Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(blobIS, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ) {....}

Comment: could tell c#,python (or) etc upadte code above and add tag

Comment: In this code I just need to extracr somehow the actual encoding of blob file in order to pass it to input stream reader

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting that azure add information about encoding during blob
> uploading process

Azure will not do that for you. This is something you would need to do yourself. When uploading blob, you would need to set the `Content-Encoding` header of the blob. You can also set this header afterwards by setting the same property through set properties method.