# How to automatically set Brotli encoding in Azure Blob storage?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, file-type, brotli

Using the Azure Portal blob storage file upload via browser, how do I make it so the system automatically detects a file uses Brotli compression and sets 'br' as encoding type?

For example, if I upload a .js file using the Azure Portal file upload in-browser, the file's content type is automatically set to "application/x-javascript".

If I upload a file with .br extension, is there a way the Azure storage could detect it is a "brotli" compressed file and thus set the content-encoding for that file to "br" automatically? Right now I have to do this manually on every file.

Comment: @NaveenSharma I was rather hoping there were configurations that could be done in the storage service rather than making upload scripts. I don't need Python scripts for it to detect .js as "javascript", or ".png" as "image/png" when I upload through the Portal interface.

Comment: Hi @LilGames, Unfortunately, Azure Blob Storage does not have a built-in feature to automatically detect the `content-encoding` for uploaded files.

Answer (score 1):

> If you upload a file with a .br extension, is there a way for Azure storage to detect it as a "brotli" compressed file and automatically set the content-encoding for that file to "br"?

Azure will not automatically add your **`content-encoding`**. If you need to upload the blob with content-encoding set to **`br`**, you can use the following Python code, which will upload the .br extension file and set the content-encoding.

**Code:**

```
import brotli
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContentSettings

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("xxxx")
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("block-image")
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("sample.br")

with open(r"path of file") as f:
    data = f.read()A
    compressed_data = brotli.compress(data)

# Upload the compressed file to Azure Blob Storage
blob_client.upload_blob(compressed_data, blob_type="BlockBlob", content_settings=ContentSettings(content_encoding="br"))
```

The above code was executed and uploaded file to the Azure blob storage by setting the content encoding.

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

- [azure.storage.blob.ContentSettings class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.contentsettings?view=azure-python)
- [Retreiving the encoding from Azure blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76763030/retreiving-the-encoding-from-azure-blob) by Gaurav Mantri.